# How do i store an ArrayList of users in a Firebase Database in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to make an app that has Lobbies of users. What i thought of is having and Model for lobby and one of its attributes would be an ArrayList of Users. But from what ive read so far, it is easier said than done. This is what i have so far...

Lobby.class (Lobby Model)

```
@Parcel
public class Lobby {
    private String owner;
    private String location;
    private double cost;
    private String startDate;
    private ArrayList<FirebaseUser> members;

    public Lobby(){

    }

    public Lobby(String owner, String location, double cost, String startDate, ArrayList<FirebaseUser> members) {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.location = location;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.members = members;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public ArrayList<FirebaseUser> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    public void setMembers(ArrayList<FirebaseUser> members) {
        this.members = members;
    }

    public String getDateText(){
        String dateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
        return dateString;
    }

    public int getTotalMembers(){
        return members.size();
    }

}
```

and this is where i save the Lobby to firebase

```
public class createLobby extends AppCompatActivity {

private static String TAG = "CreateLobby";
private TextView displayDate;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener;
private EditText locIn, costIn;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private DatabaseReference usernameGet;
private Button submitLobbyButton;
private String ownerName;
FirebaseUser user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_lobby);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    usernameGet = databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).child("userName");

    usernameGet.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ownerName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.v("Username", ownerName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    locIn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loc_input);
    costIn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cost_input);

    displayDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date_picker);

    displayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    createLobby.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                    dateListener, year, month, day);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
    dateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            month = month+1;
            String date = month + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year;
            displayDate.setText(date);
        }
    };
    submitLobbyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create_lobby_button);
    submitLobbyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            submitLobby();
        }
    });
}
public void submitLobby(){
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference lobbyRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.LOBBIES);
    String owenerMan = ownerName;
    String gameLoc = locIn.getText().toString();
    Double gameCost = Double.parseDouble(costIn.getText().toString());
    String gameDate = displayDate.getText().toString();
    ArrayList<FirebaseUser> lobbyMembers = new ArrayList<>();
    Lobby newLobby = new Lobby(owenerMan, gameLoc, gameCost, gameDate, lobbyMembers);
    lobbyMembers.add(user);
    lobbyRef.push().setValue(newLobby);
    Log.v("creator", owenerMan);
    Log.v("newLobby", newLobby.getStartDate());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lobby Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

When i run my code, an error appears saying that my getTotalMembers() function in my Lobby.class file is returning a null pointer exception. The array does not store

Comment: And why is the code you currently have not working? Are you getting any errors? Or are you getting unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem?

Comment: Or whats getting updated after you run your code, something in more detail?

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @DeepPatel edited

Comment: You should check if the members arraylist exists before you check the size to avoid getting a nullpointer exception. Something like: `if(not exists) return 0; else return size;`

Comment: @GabbyCervantes where is the Constants.LOBBIES came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try once replacing this function, and let me know, what happens:**

```
public void submitLobby(){
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference lobbyRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.LOBBIES);
    String owenerMan = ownerName;
    String gameLoc = locIn.getText().toString();
    Double gameCost = Double.parseDouble(costIn.getText().toString());
    String gameDate = displayDate.getText().toString();
    ArrayList<FirebaseUser> lobbyMembers = new ArrayList<>();

    lobbyMembers.add(user);                             // You were adding user into Array after calling constructor

    Lobby newLobby = new Lobby(owenerMan, gameLoc, gameCost, gameDate, lobbyMembers);

    lobbyRef.push().setValue(newLobby);
    Log.v("creator", owenerMan);
    Log.v("newLobby", newLobby.getStartDate());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lobby Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: replacing the function with what exactly?

Comment: With the same function in your code, 
I changed position of:
lobbyMembers.add(user);                             // You were adding user into Array after calling constructor

Comment: Thanks mate! Happy coding!

Comment: Hi again! I know this sounds strange but is it okay if I ask you to upvote the original question? :D I'm afraid ive been asking too many questions who's scores never go past 0 and ive run out sadly.

Comment: No Worries! Sometimes its okay to ask for upvote but don't do that everytime. else you will lose your points in moderator review. :P

Comment: Wc!! I don't know about other questions but this one was a relevant and valid question. Also the good thing was you had tried by yourself first and put a snippet. Nice practice.